# What am I doing wrong with Physics2D.Raycast()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with Unity2D and want to have Raycasts as inputs to my neural nets. I've tried removing all contactFilters, setting distance to Infinity with no success. Whatever I do the raycast doesn't detect any collisions.
Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, directions[i], 5f, 10);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("I CAN SEE");
            input[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            input[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Directions array:

```
Vector2[] directions = {
    new Vector2(0, 1)
    new Vector2(1, 1),
    new Vector2(1, 0),
    new Vector2(1, -1),
    new Vector2(0, -1),
    new Vector2(-1, -1),
    new Vector2(-1, 0),
    new Vector2(-1, 1)
    }
```

10 is my "Enemy" layer index

I did confirm with Debug.DrawRay that collisions should be happening

Comment: Do you have colliders on the enemies?

Comment: yes, everything else works as it should. Enemies have no problem colliding with other objects.

Comment: Surely it’s because 10 is not the layer ask to get items on layer 10

Comment: @BugFinder so I should instead pass it an array of gameobjects in layer 10? sorry if I understood your comment wrong. either way I tried it without any filters and it still didn't detect anything.

Comment: No. You need to pass a layer mask. In essence your raycast should pick up anything but layer 10. I’m on a phone so am not going to Google it all for you but I believe it should be ~1<<10 but you would need to look it up.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try that